# creating custom UITextfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield

how do i make custom UITextfield? i have created class with uitextfield as a subclass then i added label it shows up, but the border(UIView) are not showing up here is the code

```
import UIKit

class borderedTextField: UITextField{
    let viewz:UIView! = UIView()
    var border:UIView! = UIView()
    var name:UILabel! = UILabel()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.addSubview(viewz)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

    func placement(){
        border.frame.size.height = 15
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewz.addSubview(border)
    border.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
    border.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    border.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewz.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    border.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewz.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

    name.text = "whatt"
    name.textAlignment = .left
    name.textColor = UIColor.black
    name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewz.addSubview(name)
    name.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    name.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    name.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewz.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    name.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewz.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    }

}
```

and i called it programatically (without storyboard) please let me know how to solve this problem without using storyboard i need it to be full code.

```
import UIKit

class signViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
var animText:borderedTextField!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       let animText = borderedTextField()
        animText.delegate = self
        animText.placeholder = "click here"
        animText.placement()
        animText.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 500, width: 200, height: 90)
        view.addSubview(animText)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `init`

```
override init (frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
    self.placement()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.placement()
}
```

Also width of border is not active

```
border.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).active = true
```

for name

```
name.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).active = true
name.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).active = true
```

Edit

```
border.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
border.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
```

Comment: var border:UIView! = UIView()

Comment: it shows up but somehow not at the right place, it show up on the top left of the text field instead of the bottom.

Comment: because you constraint it to  viewz.bottomAnchor change to  self .bottomAnchor , also viewz has no constraints

Comment: i got this error "because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."

Comment: you must put the line  self.addSubview(viewz) inside placement function to be able to make constraints with it

Comment: lol i did not i could just self.addsubview i though i have to make another view first. thank you so much man, it become clearer to me now.

Comment: Happy coding =D